# how to check from JavaScript if loaded page has ASP.NET authentication cookie?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, authentication, cookies

It looks like JavaScript does not have access to authentication cookies ('ASP.NET_SessionId', '.ASPXFORMSAUTH')

in the http headers I can see cookies but document.cookie object does not have them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET session cookies are [HTTP-only](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#HttpOnly_cookie) by default (and rightfully so).  If you need to find out if the user is authenticated in Javascript, putting a HiddenField on the page and setting its value to 0 or 1 based on your authentication token is a much better solution.

Comment: the page is from cache - same for everybody but cookies are unique.
I need to check cookies before i will make ajax request to the server to load user-specific content. and I do not want to go to the server if user does not have auth cookies.

Comment: Well, if you switch to cookieless session you can solve this problem :)

Answer (score 3):

You could create a WebMethod which uses the following code to return a true/false value:

```
[WebMethod]
public bool IsAuthenticated()
{
    return HttpRequest.IsAuthenticated;
}
```

Call this from javascript using jQuery or MSAJAX.

Comment: From a technical standpoint, this does not actually tell if the "loaded page" is authenticated.  It tells if the AJAX request is authenticated.

Comment: The reason why I want to check in javascript it is because I do not want to go to the server (performance issue, I have 3 000 000 requests daily)